# Update a cell value in excel, while executing each row via Python 3.6 Pandas to move files

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

The Following is the code. I have added comments as to where I want the status to be updated.

**My column names**: *Copy File, Destination File, Backup File, Status 1, Status 2.*

```
import shutil
import pandas


SOURCE_CSV = r'C:\USERDATA\nhvn1\Desktop\Book1.xlsx'

print('Reading data ... ', end='')
df = pandas.read_excel(SOURCE_CSV, 'Sheet3')
print('done.')

print('Processing files:')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    source_file = row['Copy File']
    target_file = row['Destination File']
    backup_file = row['Backup File']
    print(f'{source_file} to {target_file}')
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(target_file,backup_file)
        #print status 1 as 'File Backed up'
    except IOError:
        df.xs(key='Status',level=row,drop_level=False)=True
        #print status 1 as 'File not found in destiniation'
        pass
    finally:
        shutil.copyfile(source_file, target_file)
        #print status 2 as 'Success'
```

Comment: What is your question?